# Mod rewrite localhost working fine, on server in PHP QUERY_STRING and $_GET empty

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, query-string

I have a weird problem. I develop my sites on localhost and after that i distribute it server side. Most of the time this is working as expected but now notice something weird and cannot figure out what the problem is.

On the server all RewriteRule redirects but without expected queries. Something like this is working fine on localhost but not on the server:

RewriteEngine On
....
....

```
RewriteRule .....
```

***EDIT: Changed entries for security reasons, sorry!***

....
....

Does anybody knows what is going on? Do i miss something? Why are the queries not passed thru? Is it a server configuration? Cannot find anything about it on the internet.

Thank you for your comments.

EDIT: SOLUTION below, second comment. Has something to do with what apache handles first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These things are nearly impossible to debug. But mod_rewrite offers one feature that you should set up to investigate this:

```
RewriteLog /tmp/rewritelog.txt
RewriteLogLevel 2
```

The [`RewriteLog`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog) directive however cannot be used from `.htaccess`. You need to declare it in the vhost or main server configuration. If level `2` is still insufficient, then try `3`.

Otherwise I'd just would advise you to try a `RewriteBase`, since you seem to match varying directory levels with your rules. Possibly repeat your rules in the subdirectories (`streambutler/`) again. Apaches mod_rewrite is peculiar and ignores them in the parent dir sometimes.

Comment: Hai, thanks for your reply, i appreciate that. But, i don't think there is something wrong with the rules itself but with the way of handle these rules. But why it is so different? i Will try the rewritebase. Thanks

Comment: Allright, set the rewritebase and seems to be okay. But the problem was that there was also a directory with the name streambutler/ and the apache configuration on the server checks first directory and files and then rewrite rules. So there was a confusion with the existing directory. The local server checks first the rules and then directory and files. Grrr!!!!! Change the names in the rewrite rules to for example: streambutler/ to butler/ and it is operating correctly. This headache stuff and stupid. Where can i change the look-up behaviour?

Comment: Never heard about this. That's at best a difference in Apache versions.

Comment: Always turn off the MultiViews option, as this seems to be the cause of your problems. In the .htaccess, add this before `RewriteEngine On`: `Options +Indexes -MultiViews`.

Answer (score 1):

@Erwinus, the "Perdir" functionality that you discuss is standard in Apache but not well understood.  Apache will probe for, then open and read all existing `.htaccess` files on the path to a script filename.  (Ignoring the `RewriteOptions inherit` chase which is rarely chosen) it uses the deepest `.htaccess` file that it finds that has `RewriteEngine On`.

I would therefore differ from Mario's view in that IMHO its almost impossible to get a parent directories rewrite rules to preempt a child directory set -- the default action of Apache is to ignore the parent.  I explain in a more detail in [this blog article](http://blog.ellisons.org.uk/article-59).

Comment: +1 Wow, extremely informative. Could you add a small answer and post your link on http://serverfault.com/questions/214512/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-mod-rewrite-rules-but-were-afraid-to-as as well?

Comment: @mario, sorry but I ended up writing an essay. As I said there I've made it a personal project to get to the bottom of how mod_rewrite works and I've still got a bit to go.  I want to rework this with a few of the nuances that I picked up in thinking about Qs here on stackoverflow.  I want to emphasise this point that using mod_rewrite in .htaccess process is very different to the root config use and almost need to given its own separate treatment.

Comment: Cool. Many thanks! This is also kind of a reference answer on Serverfault, so the more expert knowledge the better. And PerDir is the very thing I stumbled over myself last week. (More bemusingly, I once wrote a `mod_rewrite` reimplementation for a PHP-based webserver. But never got down to so many intrinsic details.)

Comment: The codebase is a typical FLOSS zero comments, zero documentation.  I would never have bottomed this one without doing the strace on the Apache children in my test VM. Good to swap ideas :-) T